# nestjs instantiate not injectable class

Tags: nestjs

i'm pretty new in nestJS, so you can address me directly to documentation if my question was covered there, but i can't figure out how to create instance of none-injectable class.
Here is simplified version of code

```
export default class BoardingPass {

    constructor(
        orderId: string,
        companyIATa: string,
        token: string,
        private readonly checkinOrder = new CheckinOrder(orderId, companyIATa, token) // <-- i need to instantiate CheckinOrder
    ) {}
}
```

So i need to instantiate the CheckinOrder class but it requires ApolloClient which can be provided only via nestJS DI mechanism

```
export default class CheckinOrder implements ICheckinOrder {
    private order: CheckinOrderObject;

    constructor(
        private readonly id: string,
        private readonly carrierIATACode: string,
        private readonly accessToken: string,

        private readonly apolloClient: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> // can't figure out how to pass it via DI 
    ) {}
}
```

**update**

Read about custom providers, it seems like it what i need, but as you can see there is some dynamic arguments passed to init method of CheckinOrder

```
const checkinOrderProvider: Provider<CheckinOrder> = {
    useFactory: apolloClient => new CheckinOrder('1', '2', '3', apolloClient),
    provide: CheckinOrder,
    inject: [ApolloClient]
};

@Module({
    imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot(), ApolloClientModule],
    providers: [checkinOrderProvider],
    exports: [checkinOrderProvider]
})
export class GooglePayModule {}
```

and only Apollo client is static, so its still unclear how to implement regular interface composition when class Boarding pass has instance of class CheckinOrder as property :(

Comment: How are the dynamic values of the `CheckinOrder` determined?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the factory method and use it somewhere to create your service just in time. As we do here:
https://github.com/valueadd-poland/pimp-my-pr/blob/master/libs/server/repository/infrastructure/src/lib/repositories/repository-repository.adapter.ts#L18